# Find area of Surface Calculus

Tags: calculus

[image: Here is the question]
Thoughts on how to come up with the answer for this question?
Do I plug it into the formula Integral from $a$ to $b$, $2\pi(x)(fx)$

Thanks!

Comment: $\int_0^52\pi x ds $ where $ds = \sqrt{ 1 + f'(x)^2}dx$

Answer (score 1):

By definition (in fact, it *follows* from definition), the wanted surface area is

$$2\pi\int\limits_0^5 y\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx=2\pi\int\limits_0^5\sqrt{3x}\sqrt{1+\frac3{4x}}\;dx=\sqrt3\,\pi\int\limits_0^5\sqrt{4x+3}\,dx=$$

$$\left.\sqrt3\,\pi\frac14\frac23(4x+3)^{3/2}\right|_0^5=\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}\left[23^{3/2}-3^{3/2}\right]$$